# how to disable org.slf4j logger by code?

Tags: logging, parameter-passing, slf4j

i couldn't find anything that solve my problem, i know you can help me. I want to disable logger by code, and then, activate it again. I have:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
....
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
this.logger.info("GET Request to: " + url);
```

I want that deppending a boolean "showLog" parameter, logger shows or doesn't logs. And i want to do it by code. Is it possible? Regards